# How to remove white space after and before specific character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have 4 cases: (my focus is on this part: `... *{anything}* ...`)

```
var str = "this * is * a test";
var str = "this *is * a test";
var str = "this * is* a test";
var str = "this *is* a test";
```

I want this output for all of them:

```
var newstr = "this *is* a test";
```

How can I do that?

---

**Note:** If I can do that for multiple characters like '*', '`', '~', '_' then it will be perfect.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte  ... JavaScript

Comment: `str.replace(/\*\s*(.*?)\s*\*/g,'*$1*')`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Sorry, edited

Comment: @adeneo Thanks, but your regex isn't fine for every thing https://regex101.com/r/bP0qQ7/1

Comment: Well, no! Now you suddenly have two asterisks, and that wasn't the question

Comment: @adeneo Oh, I though behind of pattern doesn't matter for regex ...

Comment: `str.replace(/(\*+)\s*(.*?)\s*(\*+)/g,'$1$2$3')`

Comment: @adeneo Perfect, why you don't write an answer?

Comment: @adeneo Sorry for asking again, but in reality I need to use that `replace` for the value of a textarea, Here is my code: `$('#idname').val().replace(/(\*+)\s*(.*?)\s*(\*+)/g,'$1$2$3');`, But it doesn't replace anything, do you know why?

Comment: You have to write it back, `$('#idname').val( $('#idname').val().replace(...) )`

Comment: @adeneo I am ashamed that I ping you again, But I stuck on a really hard problem. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3g3gf7kq/7/). When I use that regex *(in line 13),* text highlighting goes after click on `Bold`, But when I remove that line `(line 13)`, everything is fine, Now how can I have both text-highlighting and that regex? Do you know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this pattern

```
(\*+)\s*(.*?)\s*(\*+)
```

and replace with `$1$2$3`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/321)

Edited per comment below

Comment: May you please define it for {one or two asterisk}?  https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/319 *(take a look at first case)*

Comment: But now, adding them back with `*$1*` doesn't work as expected

Comment: you are doing `\*+` which will match ***** is ***** as well, not sure OP needs this

Comment: @vittore That's fine, However I just need to `*` and `**`, but that's fine

Comment: @vittore, it was modified per @stack's comment above - `need to keep all asterisk(s)`

Answer (score 4):

I initially thought you were looking to replace the asterisks that were followed by whitespace.

Use the `replace` function

```
string.replace(/(\*+)[\t\n\r]*(.*?)[\t\n\r]*(\*+)/g,'$1$2$3')
```

Breakdown

`\*+` Asterisks by default match zero or more characters. Since you are looking for literal asterisks, they must be escaped with backslashes. The `+` modifier is used because we're searching for one or more asterisks

`\t*` - As mentioned above, an asterisk represents zero or more characters. In this case we're searching for whitespace characters

`(.*?)` - This matches any character. The `?` identifier means zero or one.

`[\t\n\r]*` - This finds any whitespace character. It can be simplified to `\s`

`/g` - The global flag, which means to search for ALL instances.

`$1-$9` - These are special JavaScript regex objects.

The parentheses match capturing groups, of which there are three in the above example.

Credit goes to Adaneo for this solution.

Comment: Thank you. I will check it. +1

Comment: You've just removed the asterisk completely, and not accounted for the last asterisk that also has a following whitespace

Answer (score 3):

Following alpha bravo idea, if you want to add all the multiple characters, you can add a list of options:

```
([\*|\`|\~|\_]+)\s*(.*?)\s*([\*|\`|\~|\_]+)
```

and replace that with `$1$2$3`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yV5aF0/3)

Comment: Very good +1, Also please mention to your answer this: *.. and replace that with `$1$2$3`*

Comment: @timo the only down side to this pattern it will catch `* is ~` and such, won't match same character at beginning and end